Three way merge AST: how to match nodes that are not uniquely identified
Given a structured document like Markdown or Org mode that is recursively made up of - simplifying - sections (with title and body) and subsections, I'm looking for idea on how to possibly implement a three way merge algorithm that is aware of section deletion, insertions and movements of sections.
The sections are not uniquely identified and one big challenge is to match them in a best-effort manner. There is no qualitative constraint (or at least, none that can be formally defined) on the resulting output, except for minimizing the number of manual interventions and treating significantly different sections as insertions and having a time complexity that scales well with a realistic number of sections in a document (There's no need for this to be performed in real-time).
From the material I looked for, the most relevant is for sure A three-way merge for XML documents (Lindholm, 2004) which is addressed mainly for XML documents but could be adapted to any hierarchical document. However, I am curious to know if there is another state-of-the-art solution that I can refer to.

I don't know whether there is any literature, but given that you've found one paper, a reasonable approach would be to use Google Scholar to examine other work that cites it.
I would imagine that a plausible approach is to use an edit distance computation, where you allow multiple operations (delete section, insert section, move section, modify section), to find the minimal diff from version A to version B and the minimal diff from version A to version C, then try to merge those diffs (identifying all conflicts and relying on a human to resolve them).  If you set appropriate costs for each of the operations in the edit distance computation, perhaps this will give you a reasonable solution.
